# combine tab view with bottom navigation

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In my app I want to combine a tabView with a bottom navigation bar. I want to have three tabs and three options in the bottom bar, so there should be nine different activities in the end. My tabs and the bar are defined in my activity_main.xml, so for every selected option in the bottom bar the tabs remain the same. How can I open a new fragment which depends on the combination of the selected tab and selected bottom bar option?

Answer (score 1):

I suffered from a same problem before and here is my solution.

You will need 1 activity and 12 fragment not 9 to achieve it.

The main activity contains the bottom navigation bar, and inflate 3 fragment let's name them LeftFragment, MiddleFragment and RightFragment, **this main activity should act only as an inflator for this fragments, don't write any other code in the activity just a manager for the bottom navigation bar.**

Each one of this fragments should act as a holder or a manger for the tabs fragments, **agian don't write any code in LeftFragment, MiddleFragment and RightFragment just a manager for the tablayout.**

And your actual layout code should be in each tab fragment.
Hope this answer your question.

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you! I will test it as soon as possible. So do I get it right that the content of the activity_main is used with the corresponding changes in every other activity of the bottom fragments?